# Feeding the output of a Flow to a Broadcast in Akka Streams Graph

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am trying to write a Akka Stream graph. The code I have written is

```
val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sink1, sink2)((_, _)) { implicit builder =>
   (sink1, sink2) =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._
      val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Row](2))
      val flow = source ~> flow1 ~> flow2
      flow.out ~> bcast.in
      bcast.out(0) ~> sink1
      bcast.out(1) ~> flow3 ~> flow4 ~> sink2
      ClosedShape
})

val (f1, f2) = graph.run()
val consolidated = Future.sequence(List(f1, f2))
Await.result(consolidated, Duration.Inf)
```

This code does not compile because I cannot connect the out of flow to the in of bcast.

I can connect the out of the source to the in of the bcast, but I cannot do that because some portion is common between the two branches. So I must create the branch in the graph only after flow2

Also... I am not sure if I am writing the Graph correctly because it is returning two futures of Done and I need to combine them into a single future manually using Sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't wire your graph in 2 steps, as the `~>` combinator does not give you back a flow. It is in fact a stateful, declarative operation.

A better approach here would be to wire your graph in one go, e.g.

```
  source ~> flow1 ~> flow2 ~> bcast
                              bcast          ~>          sink1
                              bcast ~> flow3 ~> flow4 ~> sink2
```

or, alternatively you can split the declarations by adding a stage to the builder (and retrieving its shape), e.g.

```
  val flow2s = builder.add(flow2)

  source ~> flow1 ~> flow2s.in
  flow2s.out ~> bcast
                bcast          ~>          sink1
                bcast ~> flow3 ~> flow4 ~> sink2
```

Regarding the materialized `Future`s, you need to choose what is meaningful as a materialized value of your graph as a whole. If you only need one of the 2 `Sink`s materialized `Future`s, you need to pass only that one to the `GraphDSL.create` method. 
If, otherwise, you are interested in both `Future`s, it makes perfect sense to `sequence` or `zip` them together.